# jar opens on mac, not windows

Tags: java, windows, jar

I am currently developing a desktop application on my Mac, and have a "prototype" jar ready to show. The application will end up running on Windows PCs (Windows 7 with Java JRE7, no JDK will be installed on these computers).

I have edited the jar's manifest to properly locate the main class. I can now double click the jar file on my mac, and it opens perfectly.

When I try to open this same jar on Windows, I am getting "A Java Exception has occurred". This is a Java Virtual Machine Launcher Error message.

I have also right-clicked the jar>open with> made sure javaw.exe was being used to open.

Any thoughts? There are some file paths in the program but nothing that writes anything outside of the jar or creates anything new. From what I understand, using forward slashes (programmed on a mac) shouldn't have any effect when using java (Windows uses backslashes).

Any ideas?

Comment: do you have a message?

Comment: I ended up figuring it out. My project was using Java 8 SDK. Downgraded it to 7, rebuilt the jar, works like a charm now.